# Record Form and Record Edit form showing Id on the output field (lookup) instead of record name

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-record-form

I am using `lightning-record-form` and `lightning-record-edit-form` to display some records where I have several lookup-fields displayed, the lookup fields when rendered as output, should show the names of the parent records, but it is showing the `Id`.

Here is my code

```
<lightning-record-form record-id={recordId} columns="2" object-api-name="Custom_Object__c" fields={apiMAiFields}
    mode="read">
</lightning-record-form>
```

Here is the screenshot

[image]

I am getting the same result with `lightning-record-edit-form` and `lightning-output-field`.

**PS**: I have checked the access for name fields and it's enabled for the logged-in user. The same code in another sandbox working just fine.

Comment: Could this be due to the user not having sharing access to those records? Salesforce used to automatically allow the Name to be visible, even across sharing boundaries IIRC, but that did change in Spring '21 I believe.

Comment: @PhilW I have access to the records, when I click on the record I can go and see the record on the details page.

Comment: This is happening to me as well in staging. In production it seems to work fine. have you figures this out?

Comment: @LourdesMontero yes I got the answer, check below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lookup fields have to be present on the `Custom_Object__c` page layout. The documentation for the components does mention that `layout-type` attribute will define what fields are available on the form, in your case the `fields={apiMAiFields}` attribute works in a similar fashion and will rely on the page layout for actual lookup record names, otherwise you will only see field values as links.

Comment: Thanks Liu, surprisingly, adding the field to page layout solved my problem. This is the right answer. @DavidCheng